# hiding text entered in a type text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a card reader which connects to computer via USB,it's supposed to print a 10 digit number when an input is focused on and a card is placed over the card reader, it works fine but I need the code to be invisible. when I hide the text using `color:transparent`, the text is hidden but when the user double clicks on the input it shows the text!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding the `hidden` attribute on the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below-

```css
.hide {
  text-indent: -99em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="123456789"><br>
<input class="hide" type="text" value="123456789">
```

Comment: why to see and what to see? How this going to help  OP? can you please add an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```html
<input type="password" name="pin" value="abc123">
```

And if you want to hide it completely then use

```html
<input type="hidden" name="pin_hidden" value="abc123">
```